# Why Do I need user id attribute?

Tags: database, class-diagram

I am currently trying to design a social network type of website and this is the class diagram
that I have so far

[image]

at the moment I have userId and username in separate tables because I wanted to normalize these tables but now I am not sure why do I need the userId attribute? I have done research and a lot of similar projects have this attribute but I don't get why? if the username is already going to uniquely identify a particular user.

By the way I am aware I have a problem with the requests table because at the moment with the attributes given I cannot identify a primary key
Thanks

Comment: I suggest that the entire "user" class is not valid in this case (as far as I can see from your description). It has 1-1 association and does not provide any useful information.

Comment: I was beginning to think this too, thanks! back to the drawing board

Comment: It is a good thing that you are thinking in models before you code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two big reasons I can think of:

1. Optimization. SQL databases typically perform *far* better when using integer primary keys than varchar ones. Lookup-something-by-user is one of the most common operations in this environment, so this has real performance implications. Many DBAs don't like GUID/UUIDs as PKs for exactly this reason.
2. Nothing dictates that a username *must* uniquely identify users. Case in point: Stack Exchange user handles don't have to be unique, and are freely editable.

Comment: I'd add to #2 that although the original question says that usernames will be unique, this helps future-proof things if it's wanted later to allow duplicate usernames, as you mentioned. Plus, what if the user is allowed to change their username? That might involve more database operations for tables that are linked to the user, whereas an ID number can remain constant.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense, so in my case I should the user and account table and make userId the primary key?

Comment: @JWayne93 I think you forgot a word in that question.

Comment: Sorry lol, I meant to say I should combine the user and the account table then make the userid the primary key? so this way it will contain UserId, AccountType, username, password and profile picture

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me.